# Scale background image to cover DIV

Tags: css

I want to make background-image that fit to div. 
This is what I have:
[image]

CSS:

```
background-size: 100%;
background-image: url(svg/image.svg);
```

How to do that?

Comment: did you try `background-size: 100% 100%`

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
background-size: cover;
```